# Loop function question

Tags: functions

I'm new to Mathematica. Below is the code I have trouble with.

```
Do[Print[
    Subscript[C, k][x_, y_]: = 
          Subscript[q, 2 k - 1] + x*Subscript[q, 2 k] - (Subscript[q, l] + y*Subscript[q, l + 1])
   ], 
 {k, 3, 5}, {l, 3}]
```

In this loop, I want k=3 map to l=1, k=4 map to l=2, and k=5 map to l=3. However in this loop function, it loops through l=1,2,3 when k=3 and so on. So is there an automatic way or code to stop the certain looping?

Comment: Quick fix would be to leave only one iterator, `k` and instead of `l` put `k-2`.

Comment: And `Print`ing a function definition will give you `Null`. Not really useful.

Comment: Cheers Guys. The reason I have k and l is that they will make my following programming much easier. Just curious is there other ways or code can handle that? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aiming to use loop to define functions you could use `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[(Subscript[C, #1][x, y] := 
     Subscript[q, 2 #1 - 1] + 
      x*Subscript[q, 2 #1] - (Subscript[q, #2] + 
        y*Subscript[q, #2 + 1])) &, {Range[3, 5], Range[3]}];'
```

Now you can test functions are defined:

```
Table[Subscript[C, j][a, b], {j, Range[3, 5]}]
```

This yields:

```
{-Subscript[q, 1] - b Subscript[q, 2] + Subscript[q, 5] + 
  a Subscript[q, 6], -Subscript[q, 2] - b Subscript[q, 3] + Subscript[
  q, 7] + a Subscript[q, 8], -Subscript[q, 3] - b Subscript[q, 4] + 
  Subscript[q, 9] + a Subscript[q, 10]}
```

Comment: Cheers ubpdqn! That's exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!